# Prevent Users from accessing certain IP ranges when Teamviewer is active

Tags: networking, routing, teamviewer, vlan

I asked [this question on Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/changing-access-control-lists-based-on-remote-access-connections-teamviewer), but determined that possibly using a script or software might be the better solution.

I have a network with multiple VLANs and subnets that get routed to each other through a main layer 3 switch. See the link to the other question for extra details on that.

Is it possible to prevent a computer from accessing any part of the network that isn't on it's own VLAN when a Teamviewer session is active?

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a rule to the Windows Firewall to block those IP ranges. Adding firewall rules is done fairly easily [via PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/13/use-powershell-to-create-new-windows-firewall-rules.aspx). You could simply run your script before allowing access.

However, anything you do client-side is really is only an inconvenience if the support guy has admin privileges and bad intentions.

Comment: I can ensure that the user accounts don't have priviledges to mess with the firewall. The main issue is: how can I run the script automatically whenever a Teamviewer session is active? Having to manually run a script to on & off access is not a good solution since I can guarantee that the maintenance crew on site will just leave it on all the time.